# rounding any numbers by 2 with .00 decimal places as default its important that i have the .00 is there any solutions ?

Tags: php

is there any solutions for this ?.

```
$price = 4.4049494;
$price = round($price,2);

echo $price;
```

The results are: 4.4 I need 4.40 this is only an example, Need (.00) decimal as default if no other numbers in place.

I cant seem to find any information relating to this online.

I am new to this would appreciate any help.

Comment: Use [sprint()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or [number_format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) or [money_format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) when echoing the value... but DON'T USE ROUND() when displaying monetary values because then you're actually __changing__ the value of $price, not simply the way it's displayed

Comment: Prices should be stored as strings or as a decimal data type. Storing them as floats will lead to rounding errors.

Comment: If I want to buy 100,000 items at 4.4049494 dollars each, and you round that price to 4.40 dollars then multiply by 100,000, I've just cost you $494.94 (a bargain for me)... is that a good enough reason?

Comment: thanks for this i will look in to what you have said and try it, huge help that you just told me that thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [printf](http://php.net/printf) or [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) for this purpose. These functions apply a specific format (the first parameter) to a number of string, integer or float arguments (the subsequent parameter(s)) – `printf` outputs the formatted string and `sprintf` returns it so that you can store it in a variable.

```
$price = 4.4049494;
printf("%01.2f", $price);
```

An easier alternative is to use [number_format](http://php.net/number_format) but this function adds a comma between every group of thousands (makes no difference if your input number is less than 1000).

```
$price = 4.4049494;
echo number_format($price, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [number_format](http://nz.php.net/number_format) function:

```
$price = 4.4049494;
echo number_format($price, 2); //give you 4.40
```